# Iterate through pandas group of rows and filter outliers based on group mean and standard deviations

Tags: python, pandas, filter, outliers, rolling-computation

I have a column of data consisting of 100 samples. I am trying to exclude some of the samples which does not fit within a group mean and standard deviation. So, I have 10 consecutive group of data with 10 mean and standard deviation values. Finally, I want to remove outliers from each group data based on its own group mean and standard deviation values.

Here is my code:

```
Ch_37['MA']=Ch_37['Rssi-1'].rolling(window=10,center=False).mean() # moving average of 10 samples
Ch_37['std']=Ch_37['Rssi-1'].rolling(window=10,center=False).std() # moving standard deviation of 10 samples

ave= Ch_37['MA'].iloc[9::10].reset_index(drop=True) # filter the average to form 10 group
std = Ch_37['std'].iloc[9::10].reset_index(drop=True)

# remove outlier from each group based on group mean and standard deviation
new_rssi_ch_37=Ch_37['Rssi-1'].iloc[::10].between(ave.iloc[::1].sub(std.iloc[::1].mul(1)),
                ave.iloc[::1].add(std.iloc[::1].mul(1)),
                inclusive=False)
```

```
# Some of the data samples are shown below
-37
-49
-52
-69
-42
-50
-46
-34
-37
-59
-61
-72
...
```

I am stuck in thinking to iterate through each group and extracting the values

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your data so we can run your code?

Comment: @richardec, Please look below of the post. A few samples are provided. I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I have added below logic and temporarily it works fine though it does not look like an elegant solution. After every step size of 10 the for loop prints column name and data type which I am not able to ignore.

```
 for i in range(0,len(Ch_37),10):

    if k>=len(ave):
      break
    mask=Ch_37['Rssi-1'].loc[i:i+9].between(ave[k]-std[k],
                      ave[k]+std[k],
                      inclusive='both')   #.loc[i:i+9:1]
   

    print(Ch_37['Rssi-1'].loc[i:i+9][mask])
    k=k+1
```